# Can't maintain collection of pointers in C++ CLI

Tags: c#, c++, boost, collections, c++-cli

I have a frustrating problem that I'm not sure exactly how to express or what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to maintain a collection of complicated structures referenced by boost shared_pointers.
These structures were created by a regular C++ module.  I would like to do this with some kind of existing container class.  So Dictionary (would have been nice....) and array and List are all out because they can't handle an unmanaged structure.  That leaves something like vector, but I can't seem to get that to work in C++ CLI.  (I can find it, but the vector complains about something further in the build process.

I'm just wondering how other people tend to do this.  Is a boosted list a better choice?  Ideally, I'd like to associate a string name with the structures, and I want to avoid any memory management, but the simple solution is avoiding me.

OK, I think I know what the problem(s) are.  This won't work:

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::YieldTermStructure>> Curves;
```

because it's an abstract class and vector can't deal with it.  I guess the auto-sizing requires access to constructor/destructor/copy which I might not have.  There is no free lunch.

Something like this is even worse:

```
Dictionary<String^, boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::YieldTermStructure> >^ dictCurves;
```

As the managed handle stuff can't deal with the pointers.
[I am willing to admit I may be wrong-minded about something here.  If the structures are so fragile, then I either need to drill down on how to copy/replicate them or have a more delicate handling mechanism (linked list or whatever).]

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Great, the question is a bit over my head, but perhaps someone else can provide an answer now =)

Comment: @Allman, I'm still getting up to speed with some OOP concepts.  I think the bugaboo is that any collection class needs to be able to copy, replicate and destroy its entries.  This is easy for ints and strings, but for something complicated, it needs access to the Constructor,Destructor,Copy for the class.  Now what I don't quite get is you want the abstract (general) class so you can store related but diff. things in a list, but then the list wants the Cons,Destr,Copy for the specific class as well.  Seems like a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that a Boost Pointer Container would work in your case.

For a vector of pointers:

```
boost::ptr_vector<QuantLib::YieldTermStructure>;
```

For an associated container of pointers (in this case the key will be a string):

```
boost::ptr_multimap<std::string, QuantLib::YieldTermStructure>
```

The container takes ownership of the object when you insert it so you don't need to manually delete the objects.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: Hello and thank you.  This was from something long ago that I am not close to at this point.  What you wrote seems to make sense.  I'll let it perc for a bit so maybe some others can chime in, and then select it.  All in all, it's not a horrible question -- but maybe it's a cakewalk for experienced OOP types.